# Building SQLITE for the Nodewebkit (Using express.js)

Tags: sqlite, express, node-webkit

I am having problems compiling SQLite for use with Nodewebkit. After research, it seems that I am having wrong versions of the programs. So I have:
- Node
- NW
- SQLite

Apparently there must be certain version of each of the mentioned programs to make it work.

What versions of the programs I must have, so I can run this command:

```
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=0.12.3
```

This [link](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/issues/257) suggests I should have NW version 0.8.x. But I cant find it for download. Or maybe that is not the problem at all...

Answer (score 0):

I build on Mac using [node-webkit v0.12.3](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/) using the following commands:

```
sudo npm install nw-gyp -g
npm install sqlite3 --build-from-source --runtime=node-webkit --target_arch=ia32 --target=0.12.3
```

First, make sure you installed `nw-gyp` globally. Then, run the command either in the directory containing node-webkit executables (nwjs), or in a subfolder of that folder.

Running the command should then create a `node_modules` folder in the same directory as the binaries, containing the `sqlite3` module.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. If you deploy your application to another machine, how would react that application?

Comment: @roland I'm not sure I understand, what do you mean by react?

Comment: I mean "Behave". You installed the module globally on your machine. What if you deploy your app to another machine? Will SQLite be working?

Comment: @roland like with any binaries you need to build for each OS. for example, you can build on windows 32 bit to run on both win 23 and 64, and another build on mac 32.